# What is the proper way to delete a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

I created a 3D array `t` dynamically (`t` is of type `int***`). Now I am trying to delete it.

I have come across 2 suggestions:
One is that simply do

```
delete[] t;
```

and apparently, it will delete everything.

The other is to do something like

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<t1[i];j++)
    {
        delete[] t[i][j];//delete all 1D array
    }
    delete[] t[i];//delete all 2D array
}
delete[] t;//delete the 3D array
```

(`t1` stores the size of `t[i]` and `t2` the size of `t[i][j]`)

what is the best way?

Comment: The answer depends on how memory was allocated in the first place.

Comment: Off topic: `int***` will not be a 3D array. It will be an array of arrays of arrays. These can have really bad cache performance. If you're just banging something out, OK. If you need speed, consider a 1D array and a wrapper that makes it look like a 3D array.

Comment: And why not use `std::vector` in the first place ?

Comment: You need a separate `delete[]` for each `new[]` performed (likewise with `new` and `delete`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @aschepler mentions in the comments, this depends on how the memory was initially allocated. I assume that you probably allocated the memory like this:

```
int*** t = new int**[dim1];
for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
   t[i] = new int*[dim2];
   for (int j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
      t[i][j] = new int[dim3];
   }
}
```

If you allocated memory in this way, then the memory looks something like this:

```
                      [ 0 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
                +---> [ 1 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
                |     [ 2 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
                |
 t ---> [ 0 ] [ 1 ]
          |
          |     [ 0 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
          +---> [ 1 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
                [ 2 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
```

Now, suppose that you just write

```
delete[] t;
```

If you do this, then memory will look like this:

```
                      [ 0 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
                      [ 1 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
                      [ 2 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]

 t ---> xxx

                [ 0 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
                [ 1 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
                [ 2 ] --> [ 0 ][ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ]
```

In other words, you've reclaimed one of the arrays, but you've leaked the majority of the memory. Oops!

On the other hand, if you use the for-loop version of the deletion code, you end up reclaiming all the memory because you've gone through all of the pointers and freed each array allocated.

Generally speaking, every allocation should have a matching deallocation, so if you called `new[]` several times, you'll need to call `delete[]` an equal number of times.

As some of the comments have pointed out, there are probably better ways for you to manage a 3D array than to use an `int ***`. The general trend in C++ is to use objects to automatically manage memory as much as possible. Consider looking into the Boost `multi_array` type, or consider writing a wrapper around a `std::vector` that stores the entries in row-major order.

Answer (score 0):

it's so important to unallocate memory properly as much as allocating it.
we should be so cautious while creating a multi-dim array on the heap as much as while deleting it:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

    int*** ptrInt = new int**[3];

    for(int i(0); i < 3; i++)
        ptrInt[i] = new int*[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            ptrInt[i][j] = new int[3];
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            for(int k(0); k < 3; k++)
                ptrInt[i][j][k] = k;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            for(int k(0); k < 3; k++)
                cout << "ptrInt[" << i << "][" << j << "][" << k << "]: " << ptrInt[i][j][k] << endl;
    }

    // now freeing memory:

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < 3; j++)
            delete[] ptrInt[i][j];
        delete[] ptrInt[i];
    }
    delete[] ptrInt;
    ptrInt = NULL; // if we call delete again on a null pointer it's ok


    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```